# Functions of Matrices History

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, math-history

I'm currently looking for some books or papers that talk about the history of the functions of matrices. Specifically, I'm looking for the history regarding sine and cosine of a matrix. I've already looked into the book by Nick Higham, *Functions of Matrices*.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Try googling these two phrases (separately): "calculus of operations" and "operational calculus".

Answer (score 0):

What about Schaums Outline Series??

Comment: I've never heard of that. Is it something I can find on Google?

Comment: yes its available

Comment: Exactly which Schaums Outline Series would be appropriate for someone interested in the *history* of this topic? None in this series seem appropriate to me for the history of **ANY** topic ...